Why was Trump's hush money payment considered a campaign contribution?
The argument I read online is that it's part of the "catch and kill" process that is used to benefit Trump's campaign and protect his reputation. But, there are other benefits to Trump to keep such news out of the press - there are reasons he'd want to protect his reputation that are separate from the benefit it has to his campaign.
For example, if Trump got plastic surgery because he wanted to look better for his campaign, and otherwise would not have gotten the plastic surgery, is that a "campaign expense"? What if he hired a personal nutritionist to ensure he stays healthy throughout the campaign? What if he hired a ghost-writer to write a book about himself that he would not otherwise have written had he not been running? Even assuming that in all these cases it can be proven (by some recorded conversation, or witness testimony) that Trump would not have done them had he not been running a campaign -- I cannot imagine it would count as a campaign contribution, and that he could be prosecuted for "misclassifying" the expense as something else.
So to be more specific, what under the law exactly qualifies as a "campaign contribution"? And what is the precedent on charging people for paying something that, according to the prosecution, should have been filed as campaign expense but wasn't.

This seems like a silly premise. If you concede that an expenditure was made only because you're campaigning, why would the existence of some collateral benefit make it not a campaign expense? Using that test, probably nothing would be considered a campaign expenditure, because you can always come up with a collateral benefit separate from the benefit to the campaign. Salary for your campaign manager? "This guy didn't have a job, and I don't want his family to starve."

Evidence about the primary reason for the payments was introduced that was apparently convincing to the jury

@bdb484 In your example, the candidate could not reasonably argue he would have made that payment had he not been running for office.

@GeorgeWhite "Primary reason" does not make a crime. It needs to have been done to a higher standard than that - done "irrespective of his candidacy". There could be multiple reasons (1. im running for president 2. i have a wife  / family reputation to protect 3. i have a business to protect), and it needs to be proven not that the first is the primary reason, but that without it the other 2 alone would definitely (beyond a reasonable doubt) been enough to for him to do it. Of course, proving such a thing in this scenario is completely ridiculous.

@ineedahero Right, because that's exactly what your question asks: How to treat such payments if the candidate "would not have done them had he not been running a campaign."

That is your example. In Trump's example, one could reasonably expect him to make the payment had he not been running.

One could reasonably expect Trump to give a friend money to ensure his family doesn't starve. But really, who cares? Is your argument really that campaign-finance laws don't apply to contributions or expenditures if "one could reasonably expect" that they might have happened anyway?

Yes, that is exactly my point. It is also the instructions that were given to the jury. I.E., if you spend $10 million on security for your campaign speech, that is undoubtedly a campaign expense because "it would not have happened anyway", beyond any reasonable doubt.

I guess you can make that argument, but I think that means you've both misinterpreted the law and asked the wrong question.

I did not misintepret the law. I referred to the jury's instructions verbatim. "a third party’s payment of a candidate’s expenses is deemed to be a contribution to the candidate unless the payment would have been made irrespective of the candidacy.."

Michael Cohen stated, publicly, in court, under oath, that he paid the money in order to protect Donald J. Trump's candidacy. I don't see how you can interpret the statement of the person who says "I paid this money because of Trump's candidacy" to mean "I would have paid this money regardless of whether Trump was a candidate or not."

Michael Cohen also perjured himself repeatedly on the stand. And, his reasoning is not the same as Trump's reasoning. Trump's intent was on trial, not Cohen's. Cohen does not know whether Trump would have paid irrespective of his candidacy any more than you or I do.

And the defense does not need to show "I would have paid this money regardless of whether Trump was a candidate or not" is true. The prosecution needs to prove beyond reasonable doubt that it is not true.

As said in the jury instructions:

Under federal law, a third party’s payment of a candidate’s expenses is deemed to be a contribution to the candidate unless the payment would have been made irrespective of the candidacy.

The theory is elaborated on by PBS:

Donald Trump is not being charged with making that 2016 hush money payment to silence adult film star Stormy Daniels. His former lawyer Michael Cohen paid that $130,000 and did so, Cohen testified, to protect Trump's chances of winning the presidency.
Trump is charged with how he repaid Michael Cohen. Prosecutors allege Trump was responsible for falsifying 34 different business records to hide the true nature of that repayment, calling them legal fees instead, and that Trump did so intending to commit or conceal another crime, a violation of state election law.


Thank you for the jury instructions. But, how could the jury reasonably conclude guilty? They need to prove the hush money payment was "irrespective of the candidacy". If he had not been running for president, and Stormy Daniels threatened to publish her story across national news outlet, is there not "reasonable doubt" that Trump would have paid her to keep quiet? I am amazed the judge did not overrule the jury's decision here; it is flagrantly obvious there is reasonable doubt.

Also, based on this answer, going back to my example, couldn't a candidate be charged for hiring a ghost writer to write a memoir ahead of the campaign, and not classifying it as a campaign expense? Especially if he told the ghostwriter (who testified) that the memoir was being written to improve the candidate's image for the campaign. Of course, that would never sell in a court of law. Based on your answer, and the jury instruction, it sounds like there must have been politics at play in the hush money case, and that is why he was convicted - clearly, he did not break the law.

Thank you for your point. Can you update your answer with that? It is extremely important. I am curious how could it be proven it was done "irrespective of his candidacy". If, apparently, reasonable doubt about that is not enough.

Those answers clearly state that state of mind must be "proven", that is, "proven beyond reasonable doubt". Are you suggesting that a juror could have believed there was a reasonable doubt that the payment would have been made irrespective of the candidacy, and still voted to convict?
